# htaccess subdomain to domain not working

Tags: .htaccess

My goal is to accomplish the following:

non-www to www
index.html to root
anything starting with blog.example.com to root so www.blog.example.com and blog.example.com and blog.example.com/23 should 301 redirect to homepage
block a bunch of bad bots

Here is my code. It does not work as I intended. The specific problem that I have is that the blog.example.com 301 redirection does not work. why?

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*rogerbot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*exabot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*mj12bot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*dotbot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*gigabot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*ahrefsbot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*sitebot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*BLEXbot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Blekkobot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*SEOkicks-Robot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*BotALot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Alexibot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*BecomeBot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*BunnySlippers.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*CheeseBot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Foobot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*exabot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*grub.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*grub-client.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*hloader.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*httplib.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*humanlinks.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*InfoNaviRobot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*JennyBot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Jetbot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*larbin.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*LexiBot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*LinkextractorPro.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*LinkWalker.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*LNSpiderguy.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*moget.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*MSIECrawler.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*naver.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*NetAnts.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*NetMechanic.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*NICErsPRO.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Nutch.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Openbot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Openfind.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*psbot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*ProWebWalker.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*RepoMonkey.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*scooter.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Stanford.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*SpankBot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*SiteSnagger.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*suzuran.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Teleport.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*WebBandit.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*WebCopier.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Xenu.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Zeus.* bad_bot
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `www` rule comes first. Rearrange your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```